# Magento v2.1 recently bought popup window

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Can anyone suggest a extension for M2 which shows a window (left hand corner of screen) with the recently purchased items.

Have seen a few for v1.9, but can't track one down for M2.

Similar to this extension - https://www.alingaecommerce.com.au/magento-extension-someone-recently-purchased

Thanks in advance.

Terry

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)